# System freeze, on exit from screensaver (Unity)

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, mouse, freeze, screensaver

I have a midrange PC (Intel Core2-Duo 3GHz, 4GB RAM, 1.5TB storage), with latest **Ubuntu 11.10** (Oneiric) and Unity (3D).

**Description:** PC does NOT ***always*** return control after automatic timeout to screen-saver -- does **NOT** prompt for password, keyboard and mouse are still active but **NON**-functional, and is non-recoverable (requires power-off).

This appears to be a **race condition** between mouse and keyboard.  When I absently move mouse (to exit screensaver) and then quickly enter password (unprompted), this lockup condition occurs ..

Is this a known issue? Can it be resolved?

A similar mouse/keyboard zombie-state is described in: (but for **Ubuntu 11.04**)

[Freeze when resuming from screensaver or monitor-sleep-state](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45233/freeze-when-resuming-from-screensaver-or-monitor-sleep-state)

**UPDATE**

Since update to kernel 3.0.0-14 (today) this has happened 3 times.

Comment: Use another Kernel?

Comment: This isn't the root cause, was already occurring ..

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to one of my friends. We installed GNOME 3 and it stopped. I'm not sure this was the answer you are looking for but nonetheless, it is a solution.